# PHP Function or Algorithm to find what elements in an array add up exactly to a certain number

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Hi I'm looking for an algorithm or function to find what group of elements in an array add up to a certain number. There may be more than one, so I wish to return the first good group reading from left to right in the array.

For example, say I have an array of random numbers... $x = array(500, 90, 50, 200, 10, 300, 900) I wish to identify any group of array elements that add up to a given number X, say 1,000.

In this case, elements 0,3,5 of array $x are the first add up to 1,000 (500 + 200 + 300). Elements 1,4,6 also add up to 1,000 (90 + 10 + 900) but not first, so we can ignore them.
The function should return a new array with the correct index positions $y = array(0,3,5).

any help appreciated! Thanks :-)

Comment: This is called the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and in general it cannot be solved in a reasonable amount of time. Of course for such small inputs you can brute force it.

Comment: The problem is that humans can work this out intelligently, and even though you can make the algorithm think like a human for calculations like this, a program will not give up where a human will soon realize that there is no correct combination.  In other words, when you have a set of numbers with no solution, any attempt made by a program will effectively be brute force.

Comment: Is there a maximum? Such as between 1 and 4 numbers, or any collection of elements greater than 1? Also, would you get a match for 10 if the target was 10, or would that be no result?

Comment: @Flosculus: "A human will soon realize that there is no correct combination" => and a human will be wrong. Cases where you can solve this problem in your mind are so simple that your phone could have solved them a thousand times in the time it took you to read the numbers.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Hiya, the maximum is the array size. I have used a program with this feature working before, so there must be a solution even if it's a compromised one. Any reasonable working solution will do here, it doesn't have to be "absolutely perfect" just a heuristic algorithm will do. :-)

Comment: @ConorRyan I have a method that works for a finite number of grouped elements - currently trying to work out how it can be made more flexible

Comment: @Jon I was comparing the approach to the problem, humans don't iterate, but programs don't stop and think 'this is taking too long'.  While a program can accurately solve any set, in a practical scenario it is sometimes better if it doesn't try, for example Google only estimates the number of results it says it finds.

Comment: @Flosculus: Of course they can stop and think "this is taking too long" if you want them to ([random example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160264.aspx)). In any case this is a completely different subject than the original "a human will realize that there is no correct combination" -- humans are practically useless at this type of work. It would be more accurate to say "a human will realize there is no way they can find a solution except by sheer luck and give up after a few minutes".

Comment: @Jon Perhaps I should rephrase that to "a human will conclude they won't find a correct combination".  A program will certainly run more checks, but unless you want it to run for a long time (talking about very large figure numbers) it needs a boundary.

Comment: This is the kind of optimisation that's been studied by [operational research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_research). If I recall correctly it is the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). I can't give further details because I haven't worked in that for years but there's definitively no need to brute-force it.

Comment: @ConorRyan Do you what sort of size arrays you'll be dealing with? I've posted some solutions below, but not sure what size arrays to test performance with

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Hey, I marked you up there cause one of the solutions will do fine for now. Later on, the arrays could be potentially hundreds or thousands of elements, so I'm thinking of running two variations of algorithm, one first to check all arrays for two or three part matches, and then another to check for more but just a shorter length, perhaps filtering the array contents in some way to prioritise them!

Comment: @ConorRyan Yea, you could just use [array_filter](http://uk1.php.net/array_filter) to remove any elements larger than the target before passing the array into whatever function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I may have missed a 'proper' way of doing this, but I have some solutions nonetheless.

Infinite search - attempt 2 (recommended):

```
function get_parts3($arr,$target)
{
    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    {
        if($v>$target) continue;
        foreach($arr as $k2 => $v2)
        {
            if($v2>$target) continue;
            if($k2==$k) continue;
            if($v + $v2 == $target)
            {
                return array($k,$k2);
            }
        }
        $tmparr = $arr;
        $tmparr[$k] = $target+1;
        $test = get_parts3($tmparr,$target-$v);
        if(is_array($test))
        {
            return array_merge(array($k),$test);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Attempted infinite search 1 - could have performance issues on large arrays though.

```
function get_parts2($arr,$target)
{
    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    {
        if($v > $target) continue;
        $keys = array_keys($arr);
        for($i=0;$i<25;$i++)
        {
            $sum = $v;
            $parts = array();
            $parts[$k] = $v;
            foreach($keys as $k2)
            {
                if($k2 == $k) continue;
                $v2 = $arr[$k2];
                if($sum+$v2 > $target) continue;
                $sum += $v2;
                $parts[$k2] = $v2;
                if($sum==$target) return array_keys($parts);
            }
            shuffle($keys);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

A *finite* search (in this case combinations of 2 or 3 numbers):

```
function get_parts($arr,$target)
{
    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    {
        if($v>$target) continue;
        foreach($arr as $k2 => $v2)
        {
            if($v2>$target) continue;
            if($k2==$k) continue;
            if($v + $v2 == $target)
            {
                return array($v,$v2);
            }
            foreach($arr as $k3 => $v3)
            {
                if($v3>$target) continue;
                if($k3==$k2 || $k3==$k) continue;
                if($v + $v2 + $v3 == $target)
                {
                    return array($k,$k2,$k3);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Cool, the solution get_parts for a finite search of 1 or 2 works and I can use that in my program. thank you, it is a good solution. In get_parts2 I think you will repeat numbers, so I could add some code to try to differentiate them...  But nice code... appreciate it :-)

Comment: @ConorRyan No worries, get_parts3 is generally better than get_parts2, but I kept it in there as an alternate solution in case needed.

Comment: @ConorRyan If this has answered your question, please remember to mark the question as resolved by accepting the answer (click the tick under the vote arrows)

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Hi, I found your code because I need it to do exactly what it does, but I having trouble trying to understand it, when it gets crazy is the last part for get_parts3,
     $tmparr = $arr;
    $tmparr[$k] = $target+1;
    $test = get_parts3($tmparr,$target-$v);
    if(is_array($test)){
    echo "Returneo <br>.";
    return array_merge(array($k),$test);
  }
why you add 1 to target, and how can you call the function within the function, I didn't know that was possible. Return false doesnt end the function, mind explaining please? I can usually understand any code, but this is beyond me.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Nvm man, I just kept staring and it, and going over it, over and over again, and managed to undesrtand it completely, thanks for the code!

Comment: @user2958190 No worries glad to have helped. Sorry for the delay, just came on to try and answer your question when I spotted your latest comment. What with this being 2 years ago I'd have needed to plow slowly through it myself lol - on further consideration you can probably remove the `+1` if you change `$v2>$target` to `$v2>=$target`